# "no implicit conversion of nil into String" in code that shouldn't be evaluated if the object is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the code:

```
if article.link && article.link.starts_with?(`https://www.youtube.com`) then article.link end
```

The error refers to this part:

```
article.link.starts_with?(`https://www.youtube.com`)
```

But if article.link is nil, that part shouldn't even be evaluated.

Comment: Try `!article.link.nil?`

Comment: You can also use `.blank?`, which covers more cases

Comment: Can you please tell what does `article.link` value is?

Comment: Why are you using backticks for strings? Replace them with single or double quotes, see if that works.

Comment: Can you make sure you use single or double quote around the https://www.youtube.com, I think it's not from your code.

Comment: Replacing backticks with single or double quotes works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem were with `article.link` the error would be `` NoMethodError: undefined method `starts_with?' for nil:NilClass ``

In fact, the problem is with the `https://www.youtube.com` expression. It evaluates to `nil`.  Why are you using those quotes? Change them to `""` or `''`